# clang 5 and 7 + omp

Tags: c++, openmp

Hi there and thx for reading and answering if you can.

I'm trying to compile a cpp project using omp. It works fine with gcc 7.3 on linux x64 but failed with both clang 5 and 7: the linker shrieks because there is no reference to **__kmpc_barrier** and other symbols of the same kind.
However, when I issue an:

```
clang++ -openmp myfile.cpp
```

works, myfile.cpp containing omp pragmas. So, a project with multiple files using make or cmake needs something more.
Any hint ?

Comment: Have you tried -fopenmp=libomp to use gcc OpenMP implementation?

Comment: Ok, it works ! Thx for your help and I have a last question: Why is clang-7 so slooow ? I have got it compiled with gcc 7.3, but clang is 10x slower than gcc for the same source...

Comment: Compiled in release mode or debug?

Comment: In debug mode of course...

Comment: I made the same mistake a few months ago ;)

Comment: what mistake ? compile in debug mode ?

Comment: Yes. debug mode would be at least 10 times slower than release.

Comment: stackoverflow complains that we should move to a chat. Unfortunately, I can't do that, (not enough reputation).

Comment: Don't worry. Just compile in release mode and clang will get fast. If you have another question, please open a new one. I think this one is now solved.

Comment: yes it is. Thank you anyway